# Parameter value [com.mypackage.entity.MyEntity@202a30a9] did not match expected type [[com.mypackage.entity.MyEntity (n/a)]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have seen similar questions answered multiple times but I have yet to come across one exactly like the issue I'm facing.

I am trying to find entity using Hibernate and CrudRepository

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface MyOtherCRUDRepository extends CrudRepository<MyOtherEntity, Long> {

    Optional<MyOtherEntity> findFirstByMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity);
}
```

**MyEntity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(
        name = "mytable",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"field1", "field2"})}
)
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "field2")
    private Field2 field2;

    public MyEntity(String field1 ) {
        this.field1 = field1 ;
    }

    public MyEntity(String field1, Field2 field2) {
        this.field1 = field1 ;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

**MyOtherEntity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "myothertable",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"field1", "timestamp", "my_entity_id"})}
)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyOtherEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")
    @NotNull
    private MyEntity myEntity;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "field1")
    @NotNull
    private Field1 field1;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime fetchedTimestamp;

    private Double fieldX;
    private Double fieldY;
    private Double fiedlZ;
}
```

There can be hundreds of thousands of MyOtherEntity.
When I run through in the debugger the MyEntity being passed to the repository is perfectly formed and the id exists etc. The full object is there but when evaluating the findLast.. it throws the error

```
Parameter value [com.mypackage.entity.MyEntity@202a30a9] did not match expected type [[com.mypackage.entity.MyEntity (n/a)]
```

The function finding the last element and using it is being ran inside parallelStream() (Java 8). The list of MyEntity is being passed from the parallelStream as a lambda param.

```
List<MyEntity> allMyEntities = myEntityService.findAll();
List<MyEntity> myEntityPartitions = partition(allMyEntities, 100);

myEntityPartitions.parallelStream().forEach(myEntities -> {
    myEntities.forEach(myEntity -> {
        Optional<MyOtherEntity> lastMyOtherEntity = myOtherCRUDRepository.findFirstByMyEntity(MyEntity)
...
    });
}
```

*Note: The real code needs the partitions for an API call and then processes individually from the result. This example is simplified.*

Comment: Whenever you get the message about `Type X does not match expected type X` where both `x`es are the same type, your issue is that you are getting two instances of the same class loaded by different classloaders.  Two classes with the same name but loaded by different classloaders are not compatible.

Comment: @JimGarrison this was very helpful. Do you have a solution? I have searched around and can't find a consensus on how to use ParellelStreams without this issue.